# Criar um alerta de data expirada em uma Gridview em ASP.NET em C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

Estou fazendo um projeto final, onde é feito um cadastro de tarefa, descrição e data. Mas não estou conseguindo colocar um aviso/alerta/mensagem na tela para avisar ao usuário que uma tarefa está expirando. Estou programando para web em ASP.NET, C# e o Banco é SQL Server Express.
Tentei com este código, mas nada acontece.

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {           
                if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
                {
                    DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(e.Row.Cells[3].Text, "0:dd/MM/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                    if (dt < DateTime.Now)
                        e.Row.Style.Add("background-color", "red");
                }               
        }
```

Gostaria de deixar dessa forma quando uma data do sistema coincidir com o mesmo do computador, não necessariamente idêntico mas com algum contorno, ou uma cor de fundo na linha do GridViewer para destaque.

Comment: Por favor, poste o código em texto. É difícil efetuar os testes com apenas uma foto como exemplo

Comment: Coloquei o código em texto.

Comment: iDate precisa ser uma string com uma data. Caso queira usar a hora do computador pode usar o DateTime.Now ou DateTime.UtcNow.

Answer (score 0):

A comparação das datas nunca é executada por conta do `Response.Redirect`.

Você pode remover o código do redirect e substituir o IF das datas pelo código abaixo para verificar a comparação das datas.

```cs
if(dt1.Date > dt2.Date)
{
  Response.Write("Tarefa expirando.");
}
else
{
  Response.Write("TESTE");
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado tvdias, por falta de atenção minha passou despercebido o comando Response.Redirect. Enfim, coloquei conforme a sua sugestão, mas deu outro erro: "A cadeia de caracteres não foi reconhecida como um DateTime válido".

Comment: Infelizmente não deu certo. Mudei o código, mas continua sem funcionar também. Obrigado assim mesmo tvdias.

Comment: tvdias, consegui! Apenas coloquei no método certo do GridViewer. Precisei retirar o Response.Redirect. Muito obrigado pela ajuda!!!

Comment: Nesse caso é interessante criar uma resposta para a sua própria pergunta explicando detalhadamente a solução e depois aceitar a mesma. @IsraelCostaeSilva